# How to send soap XML in server expected format using Android?

Tags: android, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I need to call a webservice which expects the Android client to send the SOAP XML in a particular format i.e. the server is expecting the request XML to be sent by the Android client app. All that they have provided me is the WSDL file.
If I just read the values and set them, the SOAP message sends it in the format which is not exactly as per the XSD.

How can I convert my input values to an XML format defined in the XSD of the WSDL file before putting SOAP wrapper and sending to server? Are there any standard libraries that I can use? Appreciate any help on this.

What we sent from Android is:

```
<CustLoginId i:type=\"d:string\">xxxx</CustLoginId>
<Pswd i:type=\"d:string\">abc@123/Pswd>
<ClientDt i:type=\"d:string\">2015-03-11</ClientDt>
```

Whereas, the expected format is

```
<ns:CustLoginId>xxxx</ns:CustLoginId>
</ns:CustId>
<ns:CustPswd>
<ns:CryptType>None</ns:CryptType>
<ns:Pswd>abc@123</ns:Pswd>
</ns:CustPswd>
</ns:SignonPswd>
<ns:ClientDt>2015-03-11</ns:ClientDt>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use KSoap library to do it :
https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

There's a wiki:
https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks

Comment: @Shivv, is it useful ?

Answer (score 0):

i used [ice soap android](https://code.google.com/p/icesoap/) for this purpose 
check the [wiki here](https://code.google.com/p/icesoap/wiki/GettingStarted3)

from the wiki:

Now I've got the envelopes to send to the web service, it's about time I did something about what gets sent back. This is where the magic happens in IceSoap.

You'll recall before that I wanted to get a list of dictionaries, and that I wanted the id and name of each one. The format of the response was something like this:

```
<soap:Body>
<DictionaryListResponsexmlns="http://services.aonaware.com/webservices/">
    <DictionaryListResult>
        <Dictionary>
            <Id></Id>
            <Name></Name>
        </Dictionary>

        <!-- Other <Dictionary> objects -->

    </DictionaryListResult>
</DictionaryListResponse></soap:Body>
```

//So now I've got to make an object to hold those individual dictionaries:

```
public class Dictionary {
    private String id;
    private String name;
```

}